# How can I track how much time a logged in user spend on the site?

Tags: php, wordpress, user-management

I've created a site with PHP and WordPress, and I want to calculate how much time a logged-in user spends on the site. I have set a session value when the user is logged in so if the session expires user will automatically be logged out.

**The Solution I come up with**

I will create two cookies when the user is logged in. Both store users logged in time, and one will update using js every time mouseup/mousedown event is triggered. When the user press the log out button we will calculate the time store it in the database.

**The issue with the solution**

When the user did not press the log-out button and the session expires he automatically logged out, we will insert the data we store in cookie next time he logged in, but the problem is, Users use different kinds of systems (eg; one PC from home, one pc in office, one mobile ) so that we can't rely on cookie.

If anyone knows a better solution/method will be much appericiated.

Comment: I think I would save the login time in a databse and the logout time. When he logs out calculate the difference and to get the overall time you just add all the differences that are saved in the database together

Comment: The solution you have mentioned is possible only if the user press the logout button, most users don't do that, they simply leave the site.

Comment: Maybe create a table on your database to keep track of users sessions, something like user_id, session_id, login_date and last_active_date.
On login add the session to your table and update last_active_date on every page load.
In case you need more acurate time, you could use JS to update last_active_date every x seconds. 
If you don't want to update the DB that often, keep the last_active_date on a local log file or cache than sinc the log to the database every x minutes.